# How to get BundleKey in EntityManager after getting storage of entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to get bundleKey of any entity type after is loading from

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
```

After getStorage I am getting bundleKey Value as "type", but how to render that, as it is saying that is a protected value.
Tried to fetch like:

```
-> $node->get('bundleKey')->Value();
-> $node->getField('bundleKey')->getValue();
-> $node->bundleKey;
```

All above methods i tried to fetch Values but still no luck.

Anyone Knows how to fetch bundleKey.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Found Solution:**

Rather that loading complete storage, we can use entityDefinitionUpdateManager and get keys where you will get all id, bundle, label, etc

```
$manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$entity_type = $manager->getEntityType('commerce_product');
$entity_keys = $entity_type->getKeys();
$bundle = $entity_keys['bundle'];
```

Comment: the same is available as entity type manager getDefinition, do not use the definition update manager. Also, what are you trying to do exactly? why do you need the *name* of that? You can ust use $entity->bundle() on any entity to get the value. Also $entity_type->getKey('bundle'). Note that not all entity types have this.

Comment: @Berdir: Updated answer. I am trying to get bundleKey, and I am doing this as one of my module requires to use entity query condition. Yes every entity type doesn't have bundleKey , i need only for node, taxonomy and commerce entities to load dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `bundleKey` of your entity type by this way:

```
$type = 'commerce_product';
$bundle_key = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition($type)->getKey('bundle');
```